# IE Document Mode Changes with no Effect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, knockout.js, signalr

At our organization we have a policy applied to all users to fore IE9 into IE7 render mode for compatability with some thrid party applications. I am working on a new application that uses SignalR and KnockoutJS and I am forcing IE to be in IE9 mode using

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />`

but for some reason IE does not switch over? If I go into the developer tools it indicates that the app is rendered in IE9 mode but it doesn't actually work correctly. If I refresh IE without the developer tools open it is broken but if I refresh IE with the developer tools open the app starts working. Also manually switching to IE9 render mode fixes the issue as well. The problem is we have a lot of users so doing this manually for everyone is not practical.

The exact porblem is that only the init doesn't seem to work. Even in this messed up state IE can post messages to all the other clients just when the page initially loads no posts are returned back on IE9 that had the ploicy applied. The application works just fine in Firefox and Chrome.

I have also included the X-UA-Compatible tag in web.config with no avail. I am new to SignalR and KnockoutJS so maybe there is something I have missed?

```
<script>
    $(function () {

        function Post(message, author, postedDate) {
            this.message = ko.observable(message);
            this.author = ko.observable(author);
            this.postedDate = ko.observable(postedDate);
            this.postedDateText = ko.observable("");
        }

        function PostsViewModel() {
            this.hub = $.connection.messageHub;
            this.posts = ko.observableArray([]);
            this.msg = ko.observable("");
            this.lengthRemaining = ko.observable(1000);

            this.canPost = ko.computed(function () {
                return this.msg().length > 0 && this.msg().length <= 1000;
            }, this);

            if (ko && ko.bindingHandlers) {
                ko.bindingHandlers['jEnable'] = {
                    'update': function (element, valueAccessor) {
                        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
                        var $element = $(element);
                        $element.prop("disabled", !value);

                        if ($element.hasClass("ui-button")) {
                            $element.button("option", "disabled", !value);
                        }
                    }
                };
            }

            this.msg.subscribe(function (newValue) {
                this.lengthRemaining(1000 - newValue.length);
            }, this);

            this.updateTime = function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < this.posts().length; i++) {
                    console.log(this.posts()[i].postedDate());
                    var date = new Date(this.posts()[i].postedDate());
                    var curDate = new Date();
                    var diff = curDate - date;

                    if (diff < 60000) {
                        this.posts()[i].postedDateText("Less than a minute ago");
                    } else if (diff >= 60000 && diff < 120000) {
                        this.posts()[i].postedDateText(Math.round(diff / 60000).toString() + " minute ago");
                    } else if (diff >= 120000 && diff < 3600000) {
                        this.posts()[i].postedDateText(Math.round(diff / 60000).toString() + " minutes ago");
                    } else if (diff >= 3600000 && diff < 7200000) {
                        this.posts()[i].postedDateText("one hour ago");
                    } else if (diff >= 7200000 && diff < 86400000) {
                        this.posts()[i].postedDateText(Math.round(diff / 3600000).toString() + " hours ago");
                    } else {
                        var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
                        var day = date.getDate();
                        var year = date.getFullYear();
                        this.posts()[i].postedDateText(year + "/" + month + "/" + day);
                    }
                }                    
            };

            this.sendPost = function () {
                this.hub.server.send(this.msg(), "@User.Identity.Name.Replace(@"ACCOUNTS\","")");
                this.msg("");
                $("#dialog").dialog("close");
            };

            this.cancelPost = function () {
                $("#dialog").dialog("close");
                this.msg("");
            };

            this.init = function () {
                console.log("init");
                this.hub.server.getMessages();
                window.setInterval(function () { postsViewModel.updateTime(); }, 30000);
            };

            this.hub.client.populateMessages = function (postsArray) {
                console.log("populate posts");
                var postsCollection = $.map(postsArray, function (post) {
                    return new Post(post.message, post.author, post.postedDate);
                });

                postsCollection.forEach(function (post) {
                    postsViewModel.posts.push(post);
                });

                postsViewModel.updateTime();
            };

            this.hub.client.updateMessage = function (post) {
                console.log("received a post");
                postsViewModel.posts.unshift(new Post(post.message, post.author, post.postedDate));
                postsViewModel.updateTime();
            };
        };

        var postsViewModel = new PostsViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(postsViewModel);

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            console.log("started!");
            postsViewModel.init();
        }).fail(function () {
            console.log("Could not connect!");
        });

        $("#newpost-button").button().click(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        });

        $("#cancel-button").button();
        $("#post-button").button();

        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 256,
            width: 543,
            modal: true,
            close: function () {
                postsViewModel.cancelPost();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Does starting the SignalR connection using `$.connection.hub.start({ transport: "longPolling"})` help?

Comment: using $.connection.hub.start({ transport: "longPolling"}) does not resolve the issue.

Comment: Script won't cause this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Lukasz what happens if you change your start() code to this below?

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
console.log("started!");
$.connection.messageHub.server.getMessages();

    }).fail(function () {
        console.log("Could not connect!");
    });
```

Comment: The application functions as before still doesn't get the messages in IE9 with IE7 render mode. If I got to dev tools it actually says it's in IE9 with IE9 Standards mode... Without doing anything if i close the dev tools and refresh it works...

Comment: Not sure what effects the dev tools have on IE. If you load another site like bing.com in IE with the dev tools open and then navigate to your page, does the console window record any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out in this specific situation the console.log("") lines choke IE9 in IE7 render mode that is forced back into IE9 mode and any lines after it do not get called. Removing the console.log lines from the code fixed the issue.